# GPS camera for buildings/landscape/various with best definition $400 can get

Tags: camera

I want a camera appropriate for shooting:

- 50% buildings/landscapes
- 20% food and small objects the size of an orange
- 20% groups of people (parties, street scenes)
- 10% portraits

... under these conditions:

- 60% outside during day
- 20% outside during night (I don't expect great results at night)
- 20% inside

***Required:***

1. GPS (geolocation stored in EXIF)
2. Reliable Android app to pull a picture
3. Manual exposure setting, up to several seconds (in addition to automatic)
4. Stores pictures on SD card
5. The best picture definition/quality the better
6. Maximum $400 USD

***Would be great:***

1. Resistant to rain
2. Optical zoom to take acceptable pictures of both a castle 1 kilometer away, and an apple on a restaurant table. I don't think I would have enough motivation to carry different lenses.

***Not really necessary but would be nice:***

1. Flash
2. Android app allows to remotely take a picture

Comment: That $400 budget is very, very tight for doing anything outside at night. If you're willing to give that up, I think you'll find it much easier to find a camera that works for you.

Comment: @JMY1000: 10 years ago I had a small 100 USD digital point-and-shoot whose exposure time I would set to like 10 seconds, and it gave OK (even though grainy/noisy) results with low lighting. Actually my night shots usually have quite a lot of light in them, example: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Roppongi_Hills_North_Tower.jpg

Comment: If those extremely long exposure times are fine, then sure.